# Background-image on body loses its height: 100% with the video autoplay

Tags: html, css

I am French but I cannot find a solution to my problem here. My background-image loses its height: 100% when there is this line in my slider:

`<video autoplay loop muted="" playsinline="">`

It is therefore an animated slider containing videos, and whose HTML is:

```
<div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical">
    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
        <div class="bg-img bg-img-4">
            <video autoplay loop muted="" playsinline="">
                <source src="/media/cc0-videos/lddc.webm"type="video/webm">
                    <source src="./videos/lddc.mp4"type="video/mp4"></video>
                </div>
```

And the CSS is :

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;}

body
{
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../images/PBal1.jpg);
    background-overflow: hidden;
    *
    {
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
}
```

I disabled slider CSS and it doesn't change anything. So it comes from the line of code video that is essential to me (autoplay).
[exemple with a link](https://lecomptearebours.fr/dev/index.html)
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about providing a [mcve]. The code you've provided doesn't have a background image, or any height specifiers. Your URLs also won't resolve and could do with replacing with some publicly accessible ones. (https://www.videoplaceholder.com/ / https://placekitten.com/ ). Use the [live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) feature of the question editor.